# Excel data validation to whole column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, data-validation

I want apply data validation list to a whole column in excel 2010. How can I do that with out copying the validation rule

Comment: What's wrong about selecting the whole column and then applying the data validation?

Comment: What about the header then It also shoould be in the validation list

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Can you explain that?

Answer (score 5):

Applying data validation to a whole column is not a good practice. It is very unlikely that a manually filled spreadsheet will use over a million rows. If you want to automatically apply data validation to new rows of data, you may want to consider using an Excel Table. Set up formulas, formats and data validation in the first data row. When a new row of data is entered, these formulas, formats and data validation will be applied to the new row.

You can start formulas and data validation in the first row of a table, with a little bit of tweaking, if you don't want to have a header row.

Comment: How do we set up an Excel table to automatically apply data validation to new rows of data?

Comment: @AllSolutions, All formats, formulas and data validation that are applied to an Excel table column will be carried over into new rows.

Comment: A bit more details on how to set this up will be helpful ...

Comment: @AllSolutions, what part are you struggling with? Insert a table. Apply the data validation to the table column. It will carry over into new rows.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the best way to do this if you already have a table with data in place? For instance, what if I renamed the source of the validation and I want to update the validation setup on the main table? Is there an automated way of doing this that applies to the whole table again, or do I have to manually select all cells with data and manually update it?

Answer (score 1):

In the Excel for Office 365 desktop application Data Validation is not reliably copied to new rows in a table. (I just confirmed this is the case, and the resulting search is what brought me to this post.)

A potential solution (admittedly rather inelegant) is to (1) select the new cells without Data Validation, and at least one cell with the desired Data Validation, then (2) click Data Validation on the Ribbon. A dialog will open asking if you'd like to apply the existing Data Validation rules to the new cells and voila...

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this at all, so YMMV.

Comment: I still see the same behavior

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clicking in a cell, click on the header (A,B,C, etc) and go to: Data Tools > Data validation.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLp5L.png)

Comment: very bad idea. not advisable

Answer (score 0):

select cells you want to apply similar rules, but changing according to different reference( rows change or column change), just give one data validation correct, fix those reference you do not want to change in the formula, then it apllies to every cell

Comment: Please be a little more specific with your detail, consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state, and confirming this answer is not already answered in one of the existing answers on the post.